# SQLite does not erase when uninstalling app

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a problem.

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage

When I uninstall the app and then install it again, I notice that it is still loading old files.

When uninstalling the APP, you should delete everything, including the database, correct?

Am I doing something wrong?

My code is this:

```
var db;

try {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'database.db', location: 'default'}, function(db) {});
    });
    console.log("SQLITE OK");
}catch (err) {
    alert('Erro:' + err);
}
```

Comment: Database and other files are restored due to [auto backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html), feel free to read up on it and reconfigure it.

Comment: @Pawel Just need to use that line? <application android:allowBackup="true" ... >

Comment: allowBackup=true is the default, to disable it use "false" and all preference/databases will be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same problem. Follow solution with the help of @Pawel.

Within the **config.xml** file, there will be a tag called `<platform name 
 ="android">`. Place the code below inside.

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="false" />
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable it by setting the `android:allowBackup` to false in your AndroidManifest.xml file or in the config.xml file under the android platform section if using Cordova.

One more thing, android is designed in such a way that this only happens when you are dealing with debugging apk (not signed), not the release apk.
In the release apk, no backup will be preserved in the user's mobile upon uninstalling.
When I say "Release Apk", it is a signed APK.